# Delivering notifications just to single users by Pushwoosh

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Hullo,
I would like to employ Pushwoosh to deliver notifications to taxi drivers when reservations are made to them. So far I have configured it to deliver notifications to ALL users with the app installed from a php script, but I have not understood how to address them one by one and if that is possible with the free version.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Pushwoosh answered me and confirmed this option is only possible with the Premium account: that's a real pity.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. From the official documentation :

> If you want to send customized messages to only part of the subscribed devices you need to use our Remote API or Tags and Filters. Pushwoosh Remote API and Tags are available for Premium accounts only.

https://www.pushwoosh.com/notifications-to-singlegroups-of-devices/